# How to find ejb version in web application

Tags: ejb, version

How to find ejb version in web application?I checked in application.xml and i cant find the ejb version.

Answer (score 5):

There is no information about ejb version in the `application.xml`. It is in the `ejb-jar.xml`, if it is present.
You may try to apply the following logic:

- if there is no `application.xml` file or if it has `version="5"` or higher, then you have Java EE 5 or higher application and it will use EJB 3.0 or higher
- if you have lower version in the `application.xml`, then you will have also ejb module jar with the `ejb-jar.xml` deployment descriptor which specifies the version used.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using `eclipse` then you need right click on your `ejb project` then need to go `properties` and then go to `project facets` there you can find `ejb module` version.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the xml files like ejb-jar.xml and application.xml. At the begining of the XML, you can find uri references which tell you which version of EJB is used.

ex :

```
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd"
     version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee">
```

so here it clearly says it has version="2.1"